# How to use qrc resources in qss in qtdesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qresource

I need to create QLineEdit with the search icon on the left side and i'm doing it in QtDesigner.

I've added my search_icon.svg to my resources.qrc file and assigned this qrc as a resource of my application using resource browser of QtDesigner. The contents of resources.qrc look like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix = "/icons">
    <file alias = "search_icon.svg">search_icon.svg</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then I referenced search_icon.svg in "Edit Style Sheet" window of QtDesigner using qss:

```
QLineEdit {
    background-image: url(:/icons/search_icon.svg);
    background-position: left;
    padding: 2 2 2 25;
}
```

but search_icon.svg hadn't been displayed on QLineEdit.

QtDesigner's mainWindow.ui and resources.qrc as same as search_icon.svg are in the same directory.

Do I need to compile resources.qrc somehow so that search_icon.svg can be used in qss of "Edit Style Sheet" window of QtDesigner?

Comment: convert  resources.qrc to resources.py  file by the following  command :
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources.py  and import it into your mainWindow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to add the .qrc to the ui following the following steps:

- On the right side there should be a dockwidget called "Resource Browser"(If it is hidden then you must enable it by clicking on View->Resource Browser).

  [image]
- Then click on the left icon called "Edit Resources" and the following window will open:

  [image]
- Then you press the [image] button, select the .qrc and press the "OK" button.

With the above, the .qrc icons will be visible in the Qt Designer preview which specifically adds the following to the .ui:

```xml
  <include location="qresources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
```

Another direct way to load the icon from the .qrc is to open the Qt StyleSheet form by right-clicking on the widget and selecting the "Add Resource" option and the "Resource Browser" will appear, so you must follow the previous steps.

---

If you are going to convert the .ui to .py that contains a .qrc then you must also convert it, assuming the files are main.ui and main.qrc then you should follow the next steps:

```
pyuic5 main.ui -o foo.py -x
pyrcc5 main.qrc -o main_rc.py
```